# Filtering events between WebView and other UI Elements inside the same grid of a UWP application

Tags: c#, webview, uwp

I'm trying to build a UWP-based WebView application, and I have this basic design:

```
<Page>
  <Grid>
    <WebView Name="_webhost" DragEnter="_webhost_OnDragEnter"/>
    <StackPanel AllowDrop="True" Drop="_webhost_OnDrop" DragOver="UIElement_OnDragOver" Background="Transparent" PointerEntered="UIElement_OnPointerEntered"/>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

So the **StackPanel** is on top of the **Webview**, both of them are filling the whole screen while the **StackPanel** is actually transparent by default.

When I set `IsHitTestVisible=false` in the **StackPanel**, then all mouse-related input events are fired in the **WebView**'s contents - but the thing is, I want some (specific) events to fire in the StackPanel. When not setting that property in the **StackPanel**, it catches ***all*** of the input events, thus none of them are propagated into the **WebView**.

Note that setting event handlers for the **WebView** usually doesn't do anything - since [official docs says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview#remarks) state that it doesn't support most of the user input events inherited from UIElement.

So bottom line - I want specific events to fire in **StackPanel**, but all other events to fire in the other element (**WebView** or at least its contents). How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

In general, the input event will bubble from the children element to parent element, and the bottom same level control will not hold the event. And I tested your code the WebView `DragEnter` never trigger until set `IsHitTestVisible=false` for `StackPanel`.

> I want specific events to fire in StackPanel

If you want specific the event for `StackPanel`, you could add  [`e.Handled = true;`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.drageventargs.handled) in the event handler. But it only works for event that bubble from the children element to parent element

Comment: Thank you. I know about how events usually work but this seems be a special case. From what I tested, no mouse-input events are fired in the WebView control (the event handlers are defined in the container Page's code-behind), even when I set the StackPanel to IsHitTestVisible=false, or even when when I completely remove the StackPanel from the xaml code.

Comment: As document said *As indicated in the Events table, WebView doesn’t support most of the user input events inherited from UIElement, such as KeyDown, KeyUp, and PointerPressed*, it's best practices that  uses  `WebView.ScriptNotify` to capture the mouse event that triggered from html .

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use `WebView.ScriptNotify` in this project due to security concerns :( Is there any other possible workaround?

Comment: For some security reasons, it's hard to design, the  `WebView.ScriptNotify` is recommend way you know :).